# Does using the line out bypass my inhouse speakers on my combo amp?

Tags: amplifiers

I have a Johnson Blueline 100r combo amp and I want to connect it to an external cabinet and use them simultaneoualy. I am unsure if the line out will bypass the inhouse speakers.

Comment: Have you asked the amp suppliers or checked on their site?

Comment: Their website is archaic at best

Comment: I think I'll use a separate external amp for the cabinet and a splitter pedal.

Comment: I’m talking in general terms ‘cause all amps are a little different and I don’t know yours specifically. A line out is for sending a signal to a PA or another amplifier but not an external cabinet. It typically doesn’t mute the internal speakers. You need an external speaker output to go to another cabinet. Sometimes using the external speaker output will mute the internal speakers, you just have to try it. if your amp doesn’t have one you can use the line out to go to another amplifier.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - doesn't the line out act from the same place as 'send', like after the pre-amp?

Comment: As John says, the line-out will not power your speaker cab. That's the port from which you'll take a lead to the second amp's input. But why don't you connect your cab. to the speaker out on the original amp., and see what happens. Either only the cab. will work, or both will sound. Then you'll know. But be careful to match impedances - that speaker out is usually in parallel with the internal speaker.

Comment: The line out is usually post preamp and eq so you get your amp’s sound if you use it to send to your second amplifier, mixing board or recording input. I don’t know for sure if the effects loop is post or pre. I tried to find some pics of your specific amp online. I saw one unidentified model and it didn’t have a speaker out. I think line out to a second amp is the way to go.